# How to make an AVD with userdata.img smaller than 2.15 GB?

Tags: android-emulator

I'm trying to reduce the disk space my AVDs (Android emulator) use. I have 3 AVDs. 2 take up 4-5 GB (each), one only takes 2.7 GB. I'm trying to recreate smaller AVDs that take up no more than 2 GB. When I create a new AVD, I enter 200 MB for Internal Storage and 100 MB for SD Card. Then I create the AVD, and find that `userdata.img` takes up 2.15 GB (OS X 10.11.6).

How can I make the userdata smaller? Like my smaller AVD, the `userdata.img` is 567 MB. That might have been created by older AS, and it seems like current AS can't make it any smaller. Am I wrong?
[image: This config leads to 2.15 GB userdata]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. Hopefully they will fix.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78367980